# three.js | coloring intersected mesh recolors every mesh

Tags: typescript, three.js

I try to recolor a mesh when the mouse hovers over it. But for some reason it is not working properly, instead of giving the color red to only one, EVERY Mesh gets filled.

When debugging the intersects, it only prints out one element.

I am working with "three": "^0.132.2" in an angular / typescript environment.

```
function render() {
    raycaster.setFromCamera( mouse, camera );
    const intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( scene.children, false );
    if (intersects[0]) {
        console.log(intersects[0].object.id, (scene.getObjectById(intersects[0].object.id) as THREE.Mesh));
        // @ts-ignore
        (scene.getObjectById(intersects[0].object.id) as THREE.Mesh).material.color.set('#f00');
    }
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's very common (and preferred, for performance reasons) to reuse the same material for several meshes if you can. In this case you are probably modifying a shared material.

One way around this issue would be to keep a separate material to use on any meshes you want to highlight, swap it out and back after you are done highlighting it.

Comment: Thank you very much, that was exact the case and your hint solved it for me 